# limit on number of alternative specific variables in multinomial logit

Tags: multinomial-logit

I am trying to understand the multinomial logit model as presented in chapter 2 of "Discrete Choice Modelling and Air Travel Demand: Theory and Applications" by Garrows, and I've come across a line that I can't find an explanation for. Including some background, she writes:

"Variables can be classified as generic or alternative-specific. Variables such as the price and stops variables shown in the itinerary choice scenario in Table 2.2 are “generic” because they can take on different values within an individual’s choice set. In contrast, variables like an individual’s annual income take on a “specific” value within that individual’s choice set. Because only differences in utilities are uniquely identified, variables that do not vary across choice sets must be interacted with a generic variable or made “alternative-specific.” In addition, given J alternatives, at most J – 1 alternative-specific variables can be included in the utility functions."

I understand the distinction between generic and alternative-specific, but why can there only be "at most J – 1 alternative-specific variables" given J alternatives?

Thanks in advance.